# want to redirect to admin/login when someone adds url http://localhost/admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

my code of web.php is this I also want to tell when I use url then the browser shows me the js and css folder is shown in browser

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
Route::get('/login', 'AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/register_new', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.register.index');
Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('admin.register.new');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/logout', 'AdminController@loguot')->name('admin.logout');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.home');
});
Route::get('/', 'AdminLoginController@rediractToLogin');
});
```

and code of controller is

```
public function rediractToLogin()
{
    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add route in web.php file: (after this whole admin route group)

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminLoginController@rediractToLogin');
```

Method `rediractToLogin` must to be be defined in `AdminLoginController` controller.

Comment: if I already added the prefix admin then why should I use Route like this `Route::get('/admin', 'AdminLoginController@rediractToLogin');`

Comment: I checked your routes and everything is fine. When user adds `/admin` then redirects to `admin/login` and asks for `showLoginForm` method from `AdminLoginController` controller. Problems maybe with `showLoginForm` method? Are you returning the view?

Comment: But you don't have the same problem when user goes directly to `/admin/login`? The form is displayed? If not - problems with `blade` file.

Comment: no, when I go to admin/login it shows login form perfectly